# Swift: Swift doc github documentation tool - unable to find correct path

Tags: swift, documentation, documentation-generation

I'm trying to install and use the following auto-generating documentation tool for my Swift project:

https://github.com/SwiftDocOrg/swift-doc

It is installed correctly however when I try to generate I get the following message:

```
No public API symbols were found at the specified path. No output was written.
```

The path to my project is as follows:

```
Desktop/Development/GitClones/MyProjectFolder/
```

So I have tried this:

```
swift doc generate /Desktop/Development/GitClones/MyProjectFolder --module-name MyProject
```

The module name I am getting from build settings.

Not entirely sure the is the right forum but I'm not getting any reply from the developer and wondered if somebody here may have tried using this tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, turns out it's that none of my classes and functions are declared `public`. Once I added `public` to them, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I decided this case by key:

--minimum-access-level 
The minimum access level of the symbols which should
be included. (default: public)